# Pipe that leads to a map ends up giving a list of incorrect length

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using the `combn` function, I want to generate all possible combinations of the vector `c("1", "2", "3")` when choosing 2 elements (`m = 2`.) The code looks like this:

```
comparisons <- combn(c("1", "2", "3"), m = 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "1"  "1"  "2" 
[2,] "2"  "3"  "3"
```

I then transpose this data-frame, so it becomes this:

```
comparisons <- t(comparisons)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "2" 
[2,] "1"  "3" 
[3,] "2"  "3"
```

The last step is to generate a list, where each element is a row from this transposed data-frame. I used map, and it gave me exactly what I wanted:

```
comparisons <- map(1:3, ~ comparisons[.x, ])


[[1]]
[1] "1" "2"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "3"

[[3]]
[1] "2" "3"
```

This is all fine and dandy, but when I try to pipe all of these together in one nice assignment, the resulting list is incorrect.

```
comparisons <- combn(c("1", "2", "3"), m = 2) %>%
  t() %>%
  map(1:3, ~ .[.x, ])

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing, when I turn your matrix into a tibble and then a list I get to your desired output. Since every data frame/tibble is also a list so every column is equivalent to one element of the list.

```
package(purrr)

comparisons %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  as.list() %>%     # Up here it will get your desire output but if you want to transpose it however you can run the last line of code.
  transpose()

$a                   # Before running transpose
[1] "1" "2"

$b
[1] "1" "3"

$c
[1] "2" "3"

                     # After running tranpose

[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] "1"

[[1]]$b
[1] "1"

[[1]]$c
[1] "2"


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] "2"

[[2]]$b
[1] "3"

[[2]]$c
[1] "3"
```